# Calculate number of requests added to queue per a second - always comes back as zero

Tags: c++, arrays, fifo

I am working on a project which receives requests through an API and adds them to a FIFO. I want to be able to log the number of requests received (added on the queue) and the number of requests processed (removed from the queue). At the moment I am trying to the request received a second average.

I am doing this by having an array of longs containing 60 elements, each element will store the number of requests received in that second.

I am doing this using the following:

```
if (fifo->enqueue(crashInfo))
    {
        this->requestProcessMutex.lock();
        this->currentRequestsASecond++; //Used to get the total requests a second
        this->requestProcessMutex.unlock();
        cout << "Current Requests Incremented to " << this->currentRequestsASecond << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

From the above code the cout is showing that the counter is being incremented and then reset to 0 as expected each second.

To add the requests a second to the array I do the following, I also log out every 10 seconds what the current average is.

```
void FIFOManager::processRequestsSecondArray()
{
    int counter = 0;
    time_t lastLoggedTime = std::time(NULL);
    while (this->bitsLibrary->getApplicationStatus() != StatusManager::ApplicationStatus::Stopping)
    {

        this->requestProcessMutex.lock();
        time_t current_time = std::time(NULL);
        long timeDiff = current_time - lastLoggedTime;
        if (timeDiff >= 10) //Only log every 10 seconds
        {
            stringstream logstream;
            logstream << this->getAverageRequestProcessTime(AverageRetrievalType::RequestsASec) << " requests received a second";
            this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "FIFOManager", "processRequestsSecondArray");
            lastLoggedTime = std::time(NULL);
        }
        requestsASecondForAMinute[counter] = this->currentRequestsASecond;

        cout << "ADDING REQUEST COUNTER VALUE " << this->currentRequestsASecond << " AT " << counter << endl;
        if (counter < 59)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            counter = 0; //Only storing a minutes worth (60 secondS) so reset and start to overwrite
        }
        this->requestProcessMutex.unlock();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        this->requestProcessMutex.lock();
        this->currentRequestsASecond = 0;
        this->requestProcessMutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

The `processRequestsSecondArray` is in array which sleeps for 1 second, at each second should store the value of `currentRequestsASecond` into the array at the current second element, each minute it wraps and overwrites through the array.

The output of `ADDING REQUEST COUNTER VALUE` is always stating that it is adding `0` but `currentRequestsASecond` doesn't get reset to 0 until after the sleep has occurred so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `processRequestsSecondArray()` function looks like it would do this once a second:

1. Wake up from the `sleep_for()` call.
2. Set `currentRequestsASecond` to zero.
3. Return to the top of the `while` loop.
4. Possibly compute and print out an average from the array.
5. Store `currentRequestsASecond` in an element of `requestsASecondForAMinute`.
6. Call `sleep_for()` again.

See the problem yet?

Any changes made to `currentRequestsASecond` during the `sleep_for()` time get wiped out and are never put in the array.  You would only get a value there if the increment was just lucky enough to happen to get a request and grab the mutex in the probably very short time `processRequestsSecondArray()` unlocks the mutex, checks the `getApplicationStatus()`, and immediately locks the mutex again.  It looks like you will need to rearrange some of that logic.

Comment: Duh so obvious now, was staring at it for ages not seeing that. I've moved my reset of the counter to 0 within the while loop straight after its inserted the counter into the array. Thanks for your help